# Can jlink JRE's be used with external JAR files?

Tags: java, jar, jlink

The jlink feature in Java allows you to create a separate runtime environment for an app. Generally, all of the modules needed for this app are squashed into one large "modules" file by jlink.

I am interested in finding out if there is a way to leave out some of the modules, so that they are separate jar files, but so that jlink will be able to find them and run the application still. Is there a way to do this?

One use case of this is if you are dealing with an LGPL library, for instance. You might want the LGPL library to be left out of the giant "blob" of modules and leave it out as a separate jar, so that someone wanting to exchange the jar for a different version/tweaked version can (which is required by LGPL).

Jlink has a "requires static" statement that you can use to require an optional module. I figured that using this may work, but I've had issues with this.

When I compile a project with requires static, I've been able to run it by including the modules using the "--add-modules" switch of java. However, once I run jlink on it to create a custom image, I've been unable to get this to work.

When I try to run a jlinked project, I get ClassNotFound exceptions.

When you run jlink on a project, it creates a custom runtime image. All of the main modules of the project are put into an image file called modules. I've checked this image file using the jimage command, and I've confirmed that theis image file does not contain the modules that I declared as static.

With jlink, I've tried to put the jar files from the modules that were declared statically into the directory with the modules image. I then try to use "--add-modules" to add the modules in manually, as well as -p and -cp to specify the directory with the jars, but I still get a ClassNotFound exception.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I answered my own question shortly after posting this.

I learned two things:

1. After making a jlink runtime image, your separate jars (the requires static modules) can't be put into the same libs directory as the jlink image.

In other words, after jlink runs, you get a directory structure like this:
bin
conf
include
legal
lib

The lib folder is where the runtime image is stored. I was putting my separate jars in the lib folder, but this does not work. If you put them in a separate directory, then this works.'

2. The "-add-modules" switch has to be placed before the -m command in the sequence to run the image.

The final command to run an image might look like this:

java --add-modules org.example.module.here,org.example.another.module.here -p your_jar_directory_here -m your.main.module/your.package.here.Main

This worked for me. You have to give the add-modules switch the modules that contain the modules that you included statically, and the -p switch is given the path to the directory containing the jars with those modules.